# Is it possible to replace text with jQuery or Php?

Tags: php, jquery

Does anyone know if it is possible to use jQuery or Php to get an element and replace what is in it?

I have some dynamically generated links and I am trying to change what is in them. I think something like this would be possible with an object oriented programming language but I am unsure where to start.

Any pointers appreciated.

Here is an example of what I have for mark-up:

```
<a class="link1>1<a>
<a class="link2>2<a>
<a class="link3>3<a>
```

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
<a class="link1><p>Custom Text</p><a>
<a class="link2><p>Custom Text Number 2</p><a>
<a class="link3><p>Custom Text Number 3</p><a>
```

Comment: Do you want to make this client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can replace

```
<a class="link1">1</a>
```

with

```
<a class="link1"><p>Custom Text</p></a>
```

by calling

```
$('.link1').html('<p>Custom Text</p>');
```

Comment: hrm, Im wondering if there is a way call this after the plugin generates the links. I think that it should work, but the content is being generated dynamically. 

I know you can use .ready to fire on when the document has finished loading, but that doesn't appear to do the trick. Should I use .load in combination with a timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use JavaScript (jQuery) to select those links:

```
<script>
//setup custom text for each link
var custom_text = ['Custom Text', 'Custom Text Number 2', 'Custom Text Number 3'];

//select all links that class starts with `link` and change it's text
$('a[class^="link"]').each(function (index, obj) {
    $(this).text(custom_text[index]);
});
</script>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3JBEK/

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use `jQuery.html(string)`

eg `$('.link1').html('<p>Custom Text</p>')`

api: [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)